How to combine two vectors by a common element?
Suppose I have
vec1 = c(1,2)
vec2 = c(2,3)

How do you combine to achieve output vector 1 2 3 or 3 2 1?
Similarly
vec1 = c(3,1)
vec2 = c(3,2)

Desired output is 1 3 2 or 2 3 1.
For the life of me I cannot work this out.
I've tried intersect and union combinations but these both seem to sort the sets on output, I'm looking for an unsorted output as per example 2 above. Is there a left and right join option in R that joins on common elements? I'm trying to achieve a general function that I can pass two vectors (of any lengths with a common element) that will combine the two as per above.

If I’m understanding your goal — to have shared element(s) in the middle, with each vector’s unique elements on either side —
# added `rev()` per OP comment
join_by_common <- function(x, y) {
  c(setdiff(x, y), intersect(x, y), rev(setdiff(y, x)))
}

join_by_common(c(1,2), c(2,3))
# 1 2 3

join_by_common(c(3,1), c(3,2))
# 1 3 2

join_by_common(c(4,1,2), c(5,3,2))
# 4 1 2 3 5


if x = c(4,1,2) and y = c(5,3,2) the output is 4 1 2 5 3 instead of 4 1 2 3 5

can i use the rev function here somehow?

I would suggest editing your original post to make your requirements clearer. Including the x = c(4,1,2) and y = c(5,3,2) example.

Did you mean:
unique(c(vec1, vec2))  

[1] 3 1 2


If the order is the matter, you might find this interesting
library(devtools)
install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")
library(SOfun)

queue = unique(c(vec2, vec1))
as.numeric(moveMe(queue, "3 after 2"))

[1] 2 3 1


nope. I need the vector to in a sense reflect about itself. (1,2,3), (3,4,5) --> (1.2.3.4.5) or (1,2,4),(3,5,4) --> (1,2,4,5,3)

I'm not sure what you now describe is the same as above. But here's a solution for arranging the numbers any way you want.

In your title you said you have "a common element". We can locate that common element and reorder the vectors, then concatenate them.

The code below stands on the assumption that: The common elements is ALWASY at either the head or the tail in the vectors.
For example, a recursion can be used to list the possible ordered options
f <- function(v1, v2) {
    key <- intersect(v1, v2)
    k1 <- which(v1 == key)
    k2 <- which(v2 == key)
    if (k1 > 1 && k2 == 1) {
        u <- c(v1, v2[-1])
        list(u, rev(u))
    } else if (k2 > 1 && k1 == 1) {
        Recall(v2, v1)
    } else {
        Recall(v1, rev(v2))
    }
}

and you will obtain
> f(c(4, 1, 2), c(5, 3, 2))
[[1]]
[1] 4 1 2 3 5

[[2]]
[1] 5 3 2 1 4


> f(c(1, 2), c(2, 3))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 3 2 1


With only examples and no description other than the subject we can't be sure what you want but the following gives the same result as in each of your examples. We assume the following since these are true for every example shown:

each input has no consecutive duplicates or if it does then each such run should be reduced to a run of length 1.
the common elements are at the start or end of each input

First try proposals consisting of concatenating the vectors or concatenating them after reversing one or both giving list L. Remove consecutive duplicates from each using rle giving list L2 and take the component of L2 whose length is least.
Use verbose=print as the third argument if you want a printout of which element of L and L2 was used -- 1, 2, 3 or 4; otherwise, use the default.  With the examples below the 4th element of L and L2 are never used.  Maybe 4 never occurs in which case L could be shortened to the first 3 elements.
f <- function(x, y, verbose = c) {
  rx <- rev(x); ry <- rev(y)
  L <- list(c(x, y), c(x, ry), c(rx, y), c(rx, ry))
  L2 <- lapply(L, \(z) rle(z)$values)
  L2[[verbose(which.min(lengths(L2)))]]
}

f(c(1,2), c(2,3)) # c(1,2,3)

f(c(3,1), c(3,2)) # c(1,3,2)

f(c(4,1,2), c(5,3,2)) # c(4,1,2,3,5)

f(c(1,2,3), c(3,4,5)) # c(1,2,3,4,5) 

f(c(1,2,4), c(3,5,4))  # c(1,2,4,5,3) 

